# Filtering out just decimals form html

Tags: python, regex

I want to get this html  `[{'grade_1': '67.81%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113087042', 'academic_class': 'Algebra I - 8th Grade - 3 (D)'}, {'grade_2': '71.88%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113087763', 'academic_class': 'Computer Science  8 - 1 (E)'}, {'grade_3': '82.40%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113086978', 'academic_class': 'English 8/Boys - 3 (G)'}, {'grade_4': '90.77%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113087637', 'academic_class': 'Leadership Symphonic Band - 1 (C)'}, {'grade_7': '90.00%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113087376', 'academic_class': 'US History - 6 (H)'}]`
*The grade will be differnt every time* and turn it into something like

```
output
grade1 = 67.81
grade2 = 71.88
grade3 = 82.40%
grade4 = 90.00
ect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just print out the first key and value in each dictionary:

```
data = [{'grade_1': '67.81%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113087042', 'academic_class': 'Algebra I - 8th Grade - 3 (D)'}, {'grade_2': '71.88%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113087763', 'academic_class': 'Computer Science  8 - 1 (E)'}, {'grade_3': '82.40%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113086978', 'academic_class': 'English 8/Boys - 3 (G)'}, {'grade_4': '90.77%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113087637', 'academic_class': 'Leadership Symphonic Band - 1 (C)'}, {'grade_7': '90.00%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113087376', 'academic_class': 'US History - 6 (H)'}]
for element in data: 
        print(list(element.keys())[0], '=', list(element.values())[0])
```

---

```
grade_1 = 67.81%
grade_2 = 71.88%
grade_3 = 82.40%
grade_4 = 90.77%
grade_7 = 90.00%
```

Relying on dictionary order feels sloppy, but I think the data itself in this object is sloppy, so it's a reasonable solution.

To address your question in the comments, consider instead:

```
data = [{'grade_1': '67.81%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113087042', 'academic_class': 'Algebra I - 8th Grade - 3 (D)'}, {'grade_2': '71.88%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113087763', 'academic_class': 'Computer Science  8 - 1 (E)'}, {'grade_3': '82.40%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113086978', 'academic_class': 'English 8/Boys - 3 (G)'}, {'grade_4': '90.77%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113087637', 'academic_class': 'Leadership Symphonic Band - 1 (C)'}, {'grade_7': '90.00%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113087376', 'academic_class': 'US History - 6 (H)'}]
grades={}
for element in data: 
    grades[list(element.keys())[0]] = list(element.values())[0]

print(grades['grade_1'])
```

---

```
67.81%
```

Comment: Thanks, im now just thinking would it be possible to turn each grade into a variable like ``` grade1 = g1 ``` ect or something becuase im going to be importing this data for live updates on a website

Comment: Dynamically creating variables is a huge anti-pattern (and likely won't work). Instead you want a cleaner dictionary that is formatted like `grades={'grade_1':'67.81%','grade_2':'71.88%'...}` That's data that you can pass around and use anywhere `print(grades['grade_1'])` would output `'67.81%'` (for instance). (updated the question to show how to achieve this with your data)